# Disable/Remove Pagination numbers from React Bootstrap Table

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, pagination, react-bootstrap-table

I would like to remove all the numbers(1,2,...,n) from the pagination. I just want to display the **Prev, First, Next** and **Last** Buttons.

Here is the Table component created using the react-bootstrap-table.

An attached working example of code sandbox.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-table-pagination-c6y47)

Table Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from "react-bootstrap-table";
import { products } from "./products";

function Table() {
    const renderShowsTotal = (start, to, total) => {
        return (
            <p style={{ color: "blue" }}>
                From {start} to {to}, totals is {total}&nbsp;&nbsp;(its a
                customize text)
            </p>
        );
    };
    const options = {
        sizePerPageList: [
            {
                text: "5",
                value: 5
            },
            {
                text: "10",
                value: 10
            },
            {
                text: "All",
                value: products.length
            }
        ],
        sizePerPage: 10, // which size per page you want to locate as default
        // pageStartIndex: 0, // where to start counting the pages
        // paginationSize: 3,  // the pagination bar size.
        prePage: "Prev", // Previous page button text
        nextPage: "Next", // Next page button text
        firstPage: "First", // First page button text
        lastPage: "Last", // Last page button text
        paginationShowsTotal: renderShowsTotal(), // Accept bool or function
        paginationPosition: "bottom", // default is bottom, top and both is all available
        hideSizePerPage: true, // You can hide the dropdown for sizePerPage
        alwaysShowAllBtns: true // Always show next and previous button
        // withFirstAndLast: false // Hide the going to First and Last page button
    };
    return (
        <div className="react-bootstrap-table container mt-4">
            <h2>React Bootstrap Table with pagination</h2>
            <BootstrapTable data={products} pagination options={options}>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey={true}>
                    Product ID
                </TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="name">
                    Product Name
                </TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="price">
                    Product Price
                </TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Table;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Kabeer, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much Ravi for your awesome trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply this trick here.

Add `paginationSize` to your options

```
const options = {
  ...
  paginationSize : 1,
  ...
}
```

then apply `CSS`,

```
.page-item.active {
  display: none;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-m4vsdw)

Comment: How to show  like this "Page 1 0f 3" using pagination in react-bootstrap-next